# How should I be countering storms TvP in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran, starcraft-protoss

A good Protoss player usually has pretty good micro with their High Templars keeping them in the back and out of sight, which makes it kind of hard to EMP or snipe them. I'm having trouble countering them.

I was thinking maybe starting to research cloak for ghosts and have them sneak around when the battle starts. Backup my forces trying to dodge storms and then try to EMP the high temps. What are some other strategies that work well against storms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spreading out your units really helps with storms. Try hard to keep them separated.

Answer (score 4):

Cloak is essential for Ghost vs Templar, that additional scouting is crucial.  You will have to watch for observers, but sacrificing a ghost to emp is a necessity for a Terran bio army.

Comment: agreed. Its always a good idea to have Ghosts and a raven.  The raven can tell you if they're moving with an observer and Seeker missile does good AoE damage. If you don't see an observer you can be more aggressive with your cloaked ghosts.

Comment: @Mark I think it would be worth sacrificing a cloaked ghost at even a chance to emp Templar, but I see where you're coming from and I agree.  The only thing is you have to consider how much you're teching.

Answer (score 4):

A single ghost can nullify a nearly unlimited number of high templars. EMP drains all their energy and removes 100 (I believe) shield points.

EMP range is longer than the range of Feedback so they won't be able to snipe your ghost.

Just a note that storm is not nearly as strong as in StarCraft 1, and simply dancing your units around will avoid the vast majority of the damage (there is actually a delay after the graphic appears before the damage starts kicking in). Not to mention storm is not as effective against marauders as it is against marines.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the protoss player going anti-bio units like high templars, you should do a tech switch to mechanical units like tanks and thors.

Comment: High Templars are still very effective against Tanks and Thors. Dark Templars are also effective with the absence of Ravens and Scans.